# Call function with default arguments inside a variadic function in c++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, default-arguments

I am trying to learn variadic tamplete functions, so I tried to make a function "timeIt" that takes another function and calls it.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string leftPad(std::string str, unsigned len, char c = ' ') {
  if (str.length() >= len)
    return str;
  return std::string(len - str.length(), c) + str;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args, typename... Args2>
auto timeIt(T (*func)(Args...), Args2... args) {
  namespace ch = std::chrono;
  auto start = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  func(args...);
  auto end = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  return ch::duration_cast<ch::microseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << timeIt(&leftPad, "foo", 10) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This only compiles if I explicitly pass the last argument as ' ', as in

```
timeIt(&leftPad, "foo", 10, ' ')
```

Is there any way to use the default argument in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do the heavy lifting yourself, that can already be done by lambda functions like this (foo captured by reference as example):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string leftPad(std::string str, unsigned len, char c = ' ') {
    if (str.length() >= len)
        return str;
    return std::string(len - str.length(), c) + str;
}

// no need to do all the argument capturing for timing
// leave that to lambda functions
template <typename fn_t>
auto timeIt(fn_t fn) {
    namespace ch = std::chrono;
    auto start = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
    fn();
    auto end = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return ch::duration_cast<ch::microseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main() {
    // use a lambda function
    std::string foo{ "foo" };
    std::cout << timeIt([&] { leftPad(foo, 10); }) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a lambda that calls your function instead:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args2>
auto timeIt(T func, Args2... args) {
    //...
    func(args...);
    //...
}

std::cout << timeIt([](auto... args){ return leftPad(args...); }, "foo", 10) << std::endl;
```

Generally, you should use perfect-forwarding though, ie `Args2&&` instead of `Args2`, `auto&&` instead of `auto`, etc, and then forward with `std::forward` wherever the arguments are used:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args2>
auto timeIt(T func, Args2... args) {
    //...
    func(std::forward<Args2>(args)...);
    //...
}

std::cout << timeIt([](auto&&... args){ return leftPad(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }, "foo", 10) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

A default parameter value is not part of a function's signature. The signature of `leftPad` is just:

`std::string (std::string, unsigned, char)`

A default parameter value in a function declaration simply allows any *call site* that *directly* calls that function to omit the parameter, and the compiler will fill in the parameter with its default value *at the call site*, eg:

`leftPad("foo", 10)`

is called *as-if* it had been written as:

`leftPad("foo", 10, ' ')`

That is not the case when calling the function *indirectly*.  In your `timeIt()` function, the caller is passing `func` a *pointer* to a function.  All information is lost about any default parameter values in the pointed function, since they are not part of the function's signature. Hence *all* parameter values must to passed in to `timeIt()` explicitly so they can then be forwarded to `func`.

In your example, the type of `func` is being deduced as:

`std::string (*func)(std::string, unsigned, char)`

Hence the need for the caller to explicitly pass in `' '` for the last parameter.

As the other answers have demonstrated, using a lambda for `func` will move the *call site* of `leftPad` into a *direct* call, where the compiler is able to apply the default value as expected, eg:

`timeIt([&] { leftPad(foo, 10); })`

is called *as-if* it had been written as:

`timeIt([&] { leftPad(foo, 10, ' '); })`